# Loading same jar using ClassLoader in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader, swingworker

In my application, I am loading the class using `ClassLoader` and it's working fine. And as per requirement I have to load the class and execute that class in multiple thread simultaneously, so I used `SwingWorker` but after implementing this it's not working, not able to execute the class's methods(may be not able to load the class.).
Implementation of SwingWorker:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> 
{
int threadCount = 0;
private int max = 1000;
ConfigurationExecution _configExec;
boolean _value;
String _assemblyName;

public BackgroundWorker(ConfigurationExecution configExec, boolean value, String AssemblyName) 
{
    _configExec = configExec;
    _value = value;
    _assemblyName = AssemblyName;
}
// End
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception 
{
    ExecuteSelenium selemHelper = new ExecuteSelenium();
    selemHelper.runTest(_configExec, _value, _assemblyName);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) 
{
    int i = chunks.get(chunks.size()-1);
    System.out.println(i);
}

@Override
protected void done() 
{
    try 
    {
        get();
        ClientReflection.threadCount--;
    } 
    catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

use of above class :

```
BackgroundWorker[] threadArray = null;
public void RunTest()
{
    int maxThreads = configExec.size();
    threadArray = new BackgroundWorker[maxThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < configExec.size(); i++)
    {
        threadArray[i] = new BackgroundWorker(configExec.get(i),isFileOut,assemblyName);
                threadArray[i].execute();
    }
}
```

Below method getting called in the `doInBackground` method of `SwingWorker`:

```
private Hashtable<Object,Object> htObjClass;
private String evalReflectionFunction(String varMethodName, String varClassName,Table objTable)
{
    String strReturnValue = "";
    try
    {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> hashtable = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        .
        .
        // NOTE : below given jar path is same for all threads
        File seleniumJarFile = new File(jarpath);
        URLClassLoader myClassLoader =  new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{seleniumJarFile.toURI().toURL()},Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        if(!this.htObjClass.containsKey(varClassName))
        {
            Class<?> dynamicClass = (Class<?>) myClassLoader.loadClass("packageName."+varClassName);
            Constructor<?> cons = dynamicClass.getConstructor(RunEnvironment.class);
            htObjClass.put(varClassName,cons.newInstance(this.objRunEnvClass));
        }
        Object obj2 = this.htObjClass.get(varClassName);
        Method method = obj2.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(varMethodName, LinkedHashMap.class);
        if(method != null)
            Object retVal = method.invoke(obj2, hashtable);
        else
            strReturnValue = "Error-text";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ......
    }
    return strReturnValue;
}
```

As I am not getting any error but also not getting result.
**Is it like we can not load same jar in ClassLoader from 2 different Thread at same time?**
If anyone gone through or have solution of this kind of situation then please help.

EDIT:
If only one thread gets invoked then it's working, but not for multiple thread.

Comment: What is the `this.htObjClass`?

Comment: @bashnesnos `this.htObjectClass` is just a `HashTable` of type `Object` to hold the class instance which get created using Reflection.

Comment: Is it truly a `java.util.HashTable`? Could you please add the code for the catch section and all the fields declaration that take part in the `evalReflectionFunction` and the part of the code where you really call this method.